# How to remove people from search in mail app?

Tags: macos, mail.app

How to remove people list when you search in mail app?

Take a look at the picture:

[image]

As you can see, there's People section under search box, how can i remove "Service Desk" from appearing here?

Comment: Your question is very confusing and I am unsure about what you are trying to ask. Can you please try to rephrase your question and use proper punctuation? You can read [How to Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question that has chance at getting answered.

Comment: Look under Window > Previous Recipients. Perhaps its what you are asking for. https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19138?locale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can remove the people list from search results.
If you search, for instance, for "Service Desk", mail will lookup in any header: From, To, Subject, and other; therefore mail will include previous recipients and contacts.

**Solution 1**

Be specific about the message header to use in the search.
You can perform the search by adding the keyword "Subject": `Subject: Service Desk`

**Solution 2**

Create a smartmailbox like the one in the picture.
In this example the smartmailbox will lookup for all message containing the word "Facebook" excluding this word from sender and recipients.
You will need to double-click the smartmailbox and edit it every time you want to do your custom search.

[image: Smart Mailbox definition]

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose `Window > Previous Recipients`.
2. Remove recipients from the list: **Select** one or more names, then **click** `Remove From List`.

Comment: Already removed here, but it still appears under the people list..

Comment: Try to click the arrow in the address and remove from previous recipients